# Return second to last non empty cell in a range

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Can some one tell me how I can grab the second to last non empty cell in each roll
=LOOKUP(2,1/(C13:M13<>""),C13:M13) I used this formula =LOOKUP(2,1/(C13:M13<>""),C13:M13) to capture the last non empty cell in a row but cant how to capture the one before it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula)

```
=INDEX(C13:M13,MATCH(1,N(C13:M13<>""))-1)
```